# How to disable an item in spinner?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm working on an android project. I am using spinner to show a drop down list. I want to make some items disable on the basis of some conditions. Following is code for what I have tried:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> statusArray = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), R.array.status_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

statusArray.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

// Disable item at position 3
statusArray.setSelection(2, false);

// Set Adapter for Spinner

statusSpinner.setAdapter(statusArray);
```

This is not the exact code but similar to original one. I'm new to android. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever an selection occur in spinner on condition call setEnabled method above setAdapter method

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> statusArray = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), R.array.status_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

statusArray.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

// Disable item at position 3
statusArray.setSelection(2, false);

//Set enable disable as follow
statusSpinner.setEnabled(true/false)
statusSpinner.setClickable(true/false)

// Set Adapter for Spinner
statusSpinner.setAdapter(statusArray);
```